# Using firebase recyclerview always returns last value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

My firebase recyclerview always returns last value only.
I want to show userName in recycler view, so I used Query.

***This is what I tried***

If I choose 'Hungary', find TripInfo-Hungary node and bring users' ID.
Next, find in User node using bring from Hungary.

what I want to get is similar to this sql.
Select userID from Tripinfo where country='Hungary'
inner join User on Tripinfo.userID=User.userID.

Here is my code.

```
***Firebase realtime DB

tkitaka
  ㄴTripInfo
    ㄴHungary
      ㄴuserID1(D223Hlk5aMf17Su9rB9NeKEaT2c2)
      ㄴuserID2(dirrk65x0GTEQ8zlRYZNryqrGYH2)
      ㄴuserID2(shngJIzT8ieI1LiQ012peMHH5p13)

  ㄴUser
    ㄴuserID1(D223Hlk5aMf17Su9rB9NeKEaT2c2)
      ㄴuserName: aaa
    ㄴuserID2(dirrk65x0GTEQ8zlRYZNryqrGYH2)
      ㄴuserName: bbb
    ㄴuserID3(shngJIzT8ieI1LiQ012peMHH5p13)
      ㄴuserName: ccc
```

```
List<User> UserList;

...onCreateView...{

Query query2 = database.getReference().child("TripInfo").child(uCodeID);
query2.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener2);

}




ValueEventListener valueEventListener2 = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    TripInfo tripInfo = snapshot.getValue(TripInfo.class); 
                    userID = tripInfo.getUserID();
                    Log.d(TAG, "1일치유저★userID    "+userID); 

                    DatabaseReference UserRef = database.getReference().child("User");
                    UserRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                                for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                    String who = dataSnapshot.child(userID).child("userID").getValue().toString();
                                    UserList.clear();
                                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                                    String a = user.getUserID();

                                    UserList.add(user);

                                    Log.d(TAG, "2유저리퍼★who    "+who);
                                }
                            }
                            tripSearchAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
```

I printed log, and got this.

```
D/여행정보검색: 1일치유저★userID    D223Hlk5aMf17Su9rB9NeKEaT2c2  (userID1)
D/여행정보검색: 1일치유저★userID    dirrk65x0GTEQ8zlRYZNryqrGYH2  (userID2)
D/여행정보검색: 1일치유저★userID    shngJIzT8ieI1LiQ012peMHH5p13  (userID3)
/// These are correct values that I want. 



D/여행정보검색: 2유저리퍼★who    shngJIzT8ieI1LiQ012peMHH5p13  (userID3)
I/chatty: uid=10085(com.example.tkitaka_fb) identical 16 lines
D/여행정보검색: 2유저리퍼★who    shngJIzT8ieI1LiQ012peMHH5p13
/// But here, I just got 1. Even it is last value of userID.
```

I think I used wrong for-loop or datasnapshot. What should I do for correct code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nested listener constantly clear `UserList` for each user it finds:

```
UserList.clear();
User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
String a = user.getUserID();

UserList.add(user);
```

After you do this for all users, you end up with a list that just contains the last user.

In general your code seems off though, as you're loading all users, for each trip that you load. Worse: you use `addValueListener`, which means that if any user is changed, you're reloading all of them for each trip. That's not only incredibly wasteful, but also probably incorrect.

More typical/idiomatic is to only load the user for each trip (so one level lower in the JSON tree), and to use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` (which will load the data once, and then stop listening).

So something like:

```
DatabaseReference UserRef = database.getReference().child("User").child(userID);
UserRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
            User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
            String a = user.getUserID();

            UserList.add(user);

            Log.d(TAG, "2유저리퍼★who    "+a);
        }
        tripSearchAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```

The changes between your code and this:

- Pass in `userID` to the `UserRef` path, so that you're only loading the data for the user of the current trip.
- Remove the `for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren())` as we're only loading a single user.
- Remove the `String who = dataSnapshot.child("userID").getValue().toString()`, since you already have the same value in `userID`.
- Remove `UserList.clear();`, since otherwise you're clearing the user list after every user that you load.
- Implement your `onCancelled`, because ignoring errors is never a good idea.

Comment: Omg..you are my savior..Now my code was more concise. Thank you for help!

Comment: You're welcome. Please make sure that you understand my changes though, as that will serve you well going forward. If anything isn't clear, just ask.